# Can PHP send mail via mutt without shell_exec?

Tags: php, sendmail, shell-exec, mutt

I've been searching for the mutt equivalent to `sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` but am not having any luck.

For the sake of PCI compliance I cannot use `shell_exec`. How else might I send email via mutt?

Comment: If You cannot use exec, shell_exec, system functions, maybe it's forbidden for security reasons. So You've to do it PHP way (not trough shell executions). I always use PHPMailer, it's better library ever made (:

Answer (score 2):

Since mutt is a commandline tool and there is no php API, you cannot use mutt without exec functions. Try using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
It has almost all functionalities of mutt.

PHPMailer is one of the most popular open source PHP libraries to send emails with attachments.

- Integrated SMTP support - send emails without a local mail server
- Send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and REPLY-TOs
- Multipart/alternative emails for mail clients that do not read HTML email
- Support for UTF-8 content and 8bit, base64, binary, and quoted-printable encodings
- SMTP authentication with LOGIN, PLAIN, NTLM and CRAM-MD5 mechanisms over SSL and TLS transports